# Parallax jumbotron in Homepage content

Tags: jquery, parallax

On my Homepage content section `CMS > Pages > Home > Content` i want to have a jumbotron with a parallax effect. The Heading and text is scrolling over the background image.

I have now my Jumbotron on [my homepage](http://www.meesfrenkelfrank.com/magento). But i can not set a fixed position to the jumbotron.

Can somebody point me in the wright direction to achieve this? It must be a simple jQuery parallax effect.

**---- UPDATE 1 ----**

I try to implement it with [this extension](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js). Does anybody know where the white margin on top of the Jumbotron is coming from?